# Displaying categories items among posts

Tags: posts, categories, loop, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I'm making a website with lots of custom posts as well as custom hierarchical taxonomies. Default index (archive) page is made of bricks with photo, title and excerpt from posts. And here comes the problem, cause those index/archive pages mustn't contain only posts items (bricks), it should also contain (among the normal post items) bricks showing sub-categories of current.

Is it a good way of doing such a thing using categories, and if it is - how to achieve it?

EXPLANATION EDIT:
By bricks i understand floating containers, just the visual representation of post (or category) data. Floating thumbnails with descriptions.

Category archive page would contain items of two types: 1) posts located in current category (not subcategories) and 2) subcategories of current category. It'd be kind like files and folders structure.

Comment: The question is not clear and what are bricks here. Can you add some more explanation to it and if possible try and explain your question with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a research of a matter, i came to the conclusion.
My post types would either be the category posts with no data (parent containers) or a child posts - standard articles. My template will check if the post does have any children - if not - it will display the post itself, and if yes - it will display gathered bricks (thumbnailed excerpts) of them. Taxonomies do not have anything to do with it.